# how to compare coordinates python

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I have two different turtles, each that are separate entities, and I want to compare their coordinates, but in my code they are pictures, so 0,0 is in different places, so i have to move one to 100,-100 for it to look decent, and where I want it.

```
import turtle
turtle = Turtle()
Shop = Turtle()
Shop.up()
turtle.up()
Shop.goto(100,-100)
if (#insert comparison here):
    print("compared")
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this right, we need to deal with two issues.  First is your image offset.  Second is that turtle uses floating point coordinates so doing a simple `==` can lead to trouble.  (I.e. is `0.00001 == 0.0` for your purposes?)  Here's one approach:

```
from turtle import Turtle

customer = Turtle()
customer.up()

SHOP_OFFSET = (100, -100)
X, Y = 0, 1

shop = Turtle()
shop.up()
shop.goto(SHOP_OFFSET[X], SHOP_OFFSET[Y])

if abs(customer.xcor() - (shop.xcor() - SHOP_OFFSET[X])) < 0.5 and \
    abs(customer.ycor() - (shop.ycor() - SHOP_OFFSET[Y])) < 0.5:
    print("same location")
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the object methods

```
xcor()
```

and

```
ycor()
```

in your case you want to use

```
if (turtle.xcor() == shop.xcor() and turtle.ycor() == turtle.ycor()): #rest of code
```

Comment: yes, but I need the Shop.xcor() to be 0.00, 0.00 while it being 100, -100